# Resouce file is not loaded on using getClass().getClassLoader().getRresourceAsStream("test.json")

Tags: java, maven, junit, classloader, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using maven sure fire plugin to execute junit test cases. I have a resource test.json on src/test/resources folder.

I am loading test.json in my test case with below code snippet

```
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.json")
```

Above code is executed in a test method. But file is not loaded properly in inputstream. On executing test, resource test.json in copied to target/test-sources directory.

java.class.path has test-sources directory but test's classloader is not loading that resource file.

Comment: That's always tricky. Have you tried "./test.json" ?

Comment: Are you really sure that the file is copied to `target/test-sources` ? Usually the files from `/src/test/resources` are copied to `target/test-classes`...Furthermore you should use `getClass().getResourceAsStream('/test.json')`

Comment: sorry, that file is copied to target/test-classes directory. /test.json also not loading the file.          InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/test.json")